# user input arguments to be passed to spring application context

Tags: java, spring, program-entry-point

I have a Java application that accepts the user input for the configuration file path.I want this input configuration file path to be passed to my spring applicationContext.xml so that I can create the bean of datasource with the dburl,dbusername and dbpasswd which will be used in further classes of my application.

Is there a way to pass the runtime user parameters to the Spring application Context? If yes then how to retrieve it in the applicationContext.xml

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which holds your runtime data declare it as a Bean in applicationContext.xml and than in properties of your datasource provide the reference of that class.

Answer (score 0):

You have basically three ways to make your application context aware of run-time configuration :

- use a property file and a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` - it will work fine, but you have to use a disk file to pass data which is already in memoty
- use system properties because `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` can use them as fallback (or preferently) for a property file - no usage of disk but you much choose the name of your properties correctly to avoid side effects (typically the prefixes must be in your own name space)
- use static fields in a dedicated class or even in a bean - not necessarily very nice but *It Just Works*

Of course, whatever method you choose, be sure to initialize those data before the application context is refreshed and started.

Comment: thanks serge i am using PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer to fetch the property file resource from my disk but the problem is in the applicationContext.xml how to retrieve the property while setting the bean "${db.driverClass}" does not work :(

Comment: It should work ... Please show your `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` configuration and the structure of your property file.

Comment: here is what i configured in my class invoking main()                   GenericApplicationContext context = new GenericApplicationContext();
            XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(context);
            xmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions(new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml"));
            PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propReader = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            propReader.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(config));              
            context.refresh();

Comment: and my properties look like this                                  db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@147.128.72.91:1528/PC
db.driverClass=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.username=orausr
db.password=orapwd

Comment: I do not know if a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` can be configured outside of the `ApplicationContext` I always have them declared in the xml file as `<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"><property name="locations" value="classpath:config"/></bean>`